# Do not want my animated answers to appear on my PowerPoint print outs

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have set up slide shows were my paragraphs & bullets points have underscore lines where a red animated answer will appear on a click.

I would like to know if I can print my presentation without the animated answers to use as workbooks for our students.

Comment: You will need to turn the visibility off of each of the red lines and the turn the visibility back on.  Not an easy process. Open up the selection pane to toggle visibility.

Comment: I've got a little free add-in that might help:  http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ01017_Creating_Teacher_-_Student_editions_of_presentations.htm  it lets you designate shapes as "Teacher edition only" or "Student edition only" then turn either set of shapes on/off at will.

Answer (score 0):

These 2 macros will do the job (here in Office 365):

```
Public Sub HideAnimations()
    For Slide = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        For Each thisShape In ActivePresentation.Slides(Slide).Shapes
            If thisShape.AnimationSettings.Animate Then
                thisShape.Visible = False
                thisShape.AlternativeText = "(hidden)"              ' hijack AlternativeText to store this info
            End If
        Next thisShape
    Next Slide
End Sub

Public Sub ShowAnimations()
    For Slide = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        For Each thisShape In ActivePresentation.Slides(Slide).Shapes
            If thisShape.AlternativeText = "(hidden)" Then
                thisShape.Visible = True
            End If
        Next thisShape
    Next Slide
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

An option that does not include Macros is to add a copy of the question text box with a white, not clear, background exactly on top of the original text box. Animate this "covering" text box to disappear with previous, and order it to be the first animation. Therefore, this "covering" text box will be seen on the printed handout, and not the red lines that are hidden underneath. When showing the presentation, the "covering" text box will disappear immediately, so the red lines will show when animated.